# Memory error when using pandas read_sql with 500k row of data

Tags: python, pandas

What I am trying to do is:

1. If User A is Fraudster.
2. Then Set all Users that shared attributes with User A to Fraudster as well.

**Table:**

[image]

There are 500K rows in the table.

**My Code:**

```
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import pandas as pd
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='database',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    df_chunk = pd.read_sql("select * from tableuser",con=connection,chunksize=1000000)
    chunk_list = []  
    for chunk in df_chunk:
        chunk_list.append(chunk)       
    df= pd.concat(chunk_list)
    def expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, col_name):
        t = pd.merge(no_fraud, fraud, on=col_name)
        if len(t):
            df.loc[df.ID.isin(t.ID_x), "IsFraudsterStatus"] = 1
            return True
        return False
    while True:
        added_fraud = False
        fraud = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 1]
        no_fraud = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 0]
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "DeviceId")
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "Email")
        added_fraud |= expand_fraud(no_fraud, fraud, "MobileNo")
        if not added_fraud:
            break
    print(df)
except Error as e:
    print("Error reading data from MySQL table", e)
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        connection.close()
        cursor.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

[image]

Last Time I got the same problem when using read_sql, **Chunksize** solved that Problem. How can I use chunksize in Dataframe?

Comment: What statement causes the crash. See line number.

Comment: @Tarik I believe that the problem is def expand_fraud function and while loop. I need to set the chunk on the df so I will not get the memory error as I did in read_sql

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are dealing with chunks. This is the proposed code:

```
df['same_device_id'] = 0
fraud_devices = df[df.IsFraudsterStatus == 1]['DeviceId']
for device_id in fraud_devices:
    df[df.device_id == device_id]['same_device_id'] = 1
```

You add a column for each extra common field values. Once done for all, your fraudsters should be determined using an or operator on FraudsterStatus and the new fields.

Comment: I have to use chunk size, Otherwise, I will get the same problem in the read_sql. The problem now when I am trying to update the Dataframe.

Comment: 500,000 rows x 200 bytes per record translate to 100MB. Accordingly I do not see the point of reading in chunks and then concatenating all of these DataFrames into one. Your memory error originates from the processing in expand_fraud. That's where you should be looking.

Comment: my old code was the same as your code. It is working with 1000 rows. however, I have increased the data to 500k rows. After that, I got a memory error. I have removed the def function and the while loop. I thought they are causing the error. But it did not work so i knew that the error while trying to fetch the data. I have used the chunks and the error is gone.

Comment: Now I have added the function and the loop back to the code and get the error again

Comment: the problem with pandas is that it loads everything into memory.

Comment: Updated my answer with a new proposal algorithm that will avoid costly merges. Not sure why half a million rows cannot fit in memory though.

Comment: Load all in memory first. It should be possible, then process the data.

Comment: You can easily achieve all of this in SQL.

Comment: I have already tied to use SQL (recursive cte) as well.